# How to limit the number of opened documents and auto close the oldest ones in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I often open too many documents (source files) in Visual Studio, and end up with a long list of tabs and couldn't find the latest one I need. It also eats a lot of memory, while I don't really need the old files open. Only the recent opened files

I wonder if Visual Studio (or an extension, free one preferred) could limit the max number of open documents, and auto close the oldest (least recent unused) ones?

I am using VS 2019 16.1.6, but willing to update to newer version if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Tidy Tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davemckeown.TidyTabs) extension. It does exactly what I expected.

> Tidy Tabs is a Visual Studio extension that keeps your document well organized by closing document tabs you are no longer using.

It has an option called "Maximum Open Tabs".

> If this value is greater than 0 then Tidy Tabs will close the oldest tabs until the number of open tabs is equal to this value. The oldest tabs will be closed even if they have not exceeded the timeout value.

However the version on Marketplace only supports up to VS 2015. It is open source on [Github](https://github.com/davemckeown/TidyTabs-VisualStudio) and it supports up to VS 2017. Another [fork by AndrueCope](https://github.com/AndrueCope/TidyTabs-VisualStudio) supports up to VS 2019. You need to compile them from source.